# Systemd timer run on XX:50

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I'm having hard time figure out the format to run every hour on the :50 minute mark.

I've tried:

```
OnCalendar=00/0:50
```

But it

> Timer unit lacks value setting. Refusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find detailed description how to specify time for timer unit in `man systemd.time`:

```
Examples for valid timestamps and their normalized form:

hourly → *-*-* *:00:00
```

So I guess the value you want to put there is:

```
*-*-* *:50:00
```

Also:

> Either time or date specification may be omitted, in which case the current day and 00:00:00 is implied, respectively. If the second component is not specified, ":00" is assumed.

So it should be enough to put there just `*:50`